# Scopes in Drive Console API invalid?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'd like to use the docs scope in my app.

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/
```

Why is this scope causing an invalid entry exception when entering it into the API console?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using that scope, you probably shouldn't be for new code.

If you want to test the scope go to the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/). The API explorer probably doesn't support it.